# Init log4j2 via Spring Log4jConfigurer

Tags: spring, log4j2

Making migration from log4j 1.2 to new log4j 2. Add to pom:

```
<!-- Add log4j version 2 with 1.2 API -->
    <dependency>
<!--             <groupId>log4j</groupId> -->
<!--             <artifactId>log4j</artifactId> -->
<!--             <version>1.2.9</version> -->
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta6</version>
    </dependency>
```

And try to init it as log4j via Spring context (that works perfectly on log4j 1.2). Use for this such config:

```
<!-- Init log4j with appropriate config according to enviroment -->
<bean id="log4jConfigurer-bean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config/env/log4j-${env.variable}.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But it seems that now it doesn`t work? What I have done wrong? May be spring config should be modified? Use such dependency for spring:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I recently ran into trouble using the SpringLog4JConfigurer in a project I'm working on as well.  Do you have more than one Log4J2 configuration you want to set up?  Do you have a particular way you want to set it up?

Comment: Yes, as you see I need to init log4j in different way in case of different enviroment. What do you mean 'particular way you want to set it up'? I just want load .xml config via spring context.

Comment: Log4j2 is still in beta, so loading it via a Spring context isn't supported.  What I mean by "how do you want to set it up" is if you'd be opposed to any of the [automatic configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) approaches it provides.

Comment: It seems like via automatic configuration I haven`t ability to use different xml config, based on enviroment variable. If know some way to load different config in automatic way, please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

Half of the Spring provided Log4j 1.2 support is done, but unfortunately not the bit you're after (for which you'd need to dive into the Log4j2 Configurator class).

For web applications, reading the docs (and code where docs were not enough) at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-web/index.html, it seems you can use Log4J2's own configurer which does parameter substitution, and will load from the classpath.

Add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta6</version>
</dependency>
```

And in your web.xml, use the following:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>classloader:/config/env/log4j-${sys:env.variable}.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Note the / after classloader: and that Log4j2 requires a sys: prefix before the env variable

**However, so far, I've not been able to get this to work on a straight migration from the Spring Log4jContextListener.  It seems that Log4j2 has promise, but for now it looks like adoption will remain on a branch until it doesn't have so many gotchas, and has better documentation **

Comment: In version 2.10.0 listener class is:
   `org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener`

Comment: Hi @nikodem92. If you've got a working config based on my answer, perhaps you might suggest an edit.  You get some reputation that way.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue while trying to update to log4j2 2.17.1 with Spring 4.1.6

This version of Log4j2 has an automatic configuration process, as described here:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration

I decided to remove the Spring Log4jConfigurer from my applicationContext.xml and use the log4j2.configurationFile option instead.

Answer (score -2):

Use class path for log4j2 with latest spring dependency

```
<bean id="log4jConfigurer-bean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config/env/log4j2.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you provide additional information? Specific commands/switches that might make for a better answer?

Comment: Is it related to original question?